# link 2 stored procedure within a Crystal report

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

Is there a way to link 2 stored procedures in a Crystal report?

I have read that a stored procedure cannot call another stored procedure in a Crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so in either the database 'expert' or within a command.  However, the `JOIN` will be done in Crystal Reports `WhileReadingRecords`.

If that doesn't work for some reason, embed the second SP in a subreport, then link the main report to the subreport.

Neither of these approaches are terribly efficient.  You should consider combining the queries in a way that they can be used by CR in an efficient manner.

Stored procedures, in my opinion, should be avoided in reporting, as they:

- add complexity
- increase maintenance costs
- don't result in significant performance gains when compared to a well-structured query